# python 3 regex - find all overlapping matches' start and end index in a string

Tags: python, regex

This was my original approach:

```
string = '1'*15     
result = re.finditer(r'(?=11111)', string)      # overlapped = True   
                                                # Doesn't work for me 
for i in result:                                # python 3.5
   print(i.start(), i.end())
```

It finds all overlapping matches, but fails to get the right end index. 
The output:

```
1 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
2 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 1), match=''>
3 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 2), match=''>
4 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 3), match=''>
(and so on..)
```

**My Question:** 
How can I find all overlapping matches, and get all the start and end index right as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you get is related to the fact that a lookahead is a [zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that consumes (i.e. adds to the match result) no text. It is a mere position in the string. Thus, all your matches start and end at the same location in the string.

You need to enclose the lookahead pattern with a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (i.e. `(?=(11111))`) and access start and end of group *1* (with `i.start(1)` and `i.end(1)`):

```
import re
s = '1'*15     
result = re.finditer(r'(?=(11111))', s)

for i in result:
    print(i.start(1), i.end(1))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/M21znx), its output is

```
(0, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 7)
(3, 8)
(4, 9)
(5, 10)
(6, 11)
(7, 12)
(8, 13)
(9, 14)
(10, 15)
```

Comment: Why do you have to type a '1' in: "i.start(1)" and "i.end(1)" ?                           
In my head "i.start()" should be enough, apparently not..

Comment: You need to get Group 1 value start and end positions. `i.start()` = `i.start(0)`, the entire match start position. The match is an empty string, a position in the string, but the capturing group holds the actual value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have a more complicated sequence to find : r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?=TAG|TGA|TAA))' . I can get right starts and ends with start(1) end(1) or span(1) my question is how do I find the corrisponding match (string). Results gave empty matches :  match='' (i.e. : (4056, 4152), 4056, 4152, <re.Match object; span=(4056, 4056), match=''>)

Comment: @pippo1980 The whole match value will always be empty when using such regexes. You need to use `re.findall`, or `[x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)]`

Comment: This works only for the samples like the one provided by OP, where we have constant number of characters inside pattern. Consider e.g. `s='1222122112221112221'` and `list(map(lambda x: x.group(1), re.finditer(r'(?=(1(.*)1))', s)))` (I know generalization is not obligatory, but this answer was quoted on handful of other questions, with similarly matching sample - making impression, that it's generic).

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, generic case of finding all matches overlapping and non-overlapping - all along SO this solution is mentioned, however it fits examples provided in respective OP's provided sample - it's not a generic solution addressing the main premise of finding all matches overlapping and non overlapping (because it covers it only with caveat that pattern length has to be fixed). I genuinely don't know how to go about it - whether we should reopen old questions, closed as duplicate or ask specific question looking for generic solution. I'm looking for solution myself too...

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski The solution in this thread *is* generic, you have a *special* use case. You say you have `s='1222122112221112221'`. What is the result you want to obtain? (No, it is not obvious, and if you have a question, you must provide these details.)

Answer (score -1):

Can you compare with this implementation and see where the differences might be.

```
match = re.finditer(r'111','test111 end111 and another 111')
for i in match:
    print(i.start(),i.end()
```

If this is not working for you kindly share a sample of you data

Comment: I doesn't even have to run it to tell that that wasn't what I was looking for.